# Send notification to disconnected user using socket io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new in socket development. I am creating chat using socket io, frontend is ios and backend is node js. I want to send message notification for disconnected users. Like we get notification if whatsapp is not opened. How can I do that ?

Answer (score -1):

You can catch the person's exit with Socket.io and send a notification with push.js

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
     console.log('user disconnected');

     Push.create(data.user_name + " | Chat", {
        body: data.desc,
        icon: "https://pushjs.org/images/icon.png",
        tag: "chat",
        link: "http://localhost:8080/chat",
        timeout: 5000,
        onClick: function () {
              window.focus();
              this.close();
        }
    });
});
```